# My delete button keeps on displaying a message box "record successfully deleted" even when the data provided is not in the database(ms access)

Tags: java, database, eclipse, ms-access

I'm working on a library management system, using ms access as the database. My "delete" button can delete a record without a problem but what concerns me is the fact that it prints/displays the JOptionPane messageDialog ("Record successfully deleted ") even when the entry provided is not stored on the database, and worse, even when all the JTextFields are empty. the delete button is named as b11. any help,please?

Here is the code        if(ee.getSource()==b11){

```
            int f = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you really want to delete?","Delete",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(f==0){
            try 
            {
            ps=con.prepareStatement("Delete from Book where BookID=?");
            ps.setString(1,tt11.getText());
            int i;
            i=ps.executeUpdate(); 
            clearBk();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record deleted successfully","Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Could not delete Record!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The statement should execute without an exception even if the id doesn't exist. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that the `int i` you have may return 1 (or more) if it deletes something, and 0 if nothing is deleted.

Comment: execute update will return 0 when no rows have been deleted

Comment: @ControlAltDel thanks for verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply condition like

```
if(i>0){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record deleted successfully","Information"
                                                 ,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

[PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())
Always returns either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

So you dialog box will always statement always executes even though no records got affected

Comment: @Compass and ControlAltDel thanks guys,your answers made a lot of sense to me. It really worked for me,again thanks.

Comment: you rock sir, Thanks alot @SparkOn!  As soon as i read your answer(code) all the theories made sense to me.Namaste!